# how to use try{} catch{} finally{}

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

how I can use `try { } catch { }` for the following script?
its a little bit confusing for me to use try/catch

```
stages {
stage ('something') {
    agent any
    steps {
        script {
            something
            ]) {
                sh "something"
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple example of a scripted pipeline with try/catch/finally.

```
node('<Node Name>') {
        stage("<Stage Name>") {
            try {
                // Your logic/code
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // depends what you want to do with the exception
                // You can even suppress the exception means not to fail the build
                // or do something and than throw it
            } finally {
                // whatever you will put here will always gets executed
            }
        }
    }
```